# Python - Заметить букву в строке

Tags: python

Нужно, чтобы получилось такое условие:

> Если в списке есть хоть одна буква напечатать "Пожалуйста введите цифру!"

Answer (score 1):

```py
def has_letter(items):
    return any(c.isalpha() for c in items)

# Более привычный алгоритм:
# def has_letter(items):
#     for c in items:
#         if c.isalpha():
#             return True
# 
#     return False

items = ['1', '3', '4']
print(has_letter(items))  # False

items = ['у', '1', '3', '4']
print(has_letter(items))  # True

items = ['f', '1', '3', '4']
print(has_letter(items))  # True
```

---

```
items = ['у', '1', '3', '4']
if has_letter(items):
    print("Пожалуйста введите цифру!")
```

Comment: Вот интересно, кто там прошелся минусометом по этой страничке и почему :) Ответ правильный, соответствует вопросу.

Comment: это явно учебное задание

Comment: @AndrioSkur, и что, что учебное? Теперь тряпками закидать задающего и всех, кто захотел помочь? Оо

Comment: @AndrioSkur, какая связь между вопросом - учебным заданием и минусом ответу?

Comment: А тошо если вы будете отвечать на вопросы, то их будут продолжать задавать. Вот вопрос по тревоге закрили, но это без толку ответ то получен...

Comment: @AndrioSkur, этот сайт и нужен для того, чтобы на нем задавали вопросы и давали ответы. По вашему, чем плохи ответы на учебные задания?

Comment: "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу" – Ну и где в вопросе попытка решения?

Comment: Такую тревогу делал не я. Если она вам не нравиться, то можете сходить на мету и высказывать недовольства там)

Comment: @AndrioSkur, вы что, я не про вопрос ведь спрашивал. Вы дали понять, что минусование ответа вопросу по учебному заданию возможно (и возможно поставили минус, но не суть важно). Вот мне и интересно почему вы так думаете? Кст, вот вам обсуждение на мете о подобных ответах на подобные вопросы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/201445

Answer (score 0):

```
num = None
for letter in list:
    if letter.isalpha():
        num = input("Пожалуйста введите цифру")
        break
```

Далее обращайтесь к `num`, туда будет записано значение, которое вы введете в консоли.

В случае, если Вам не нужно хранить/использовать дальше введенную цифру, а надо лишь вывести сообщение в консоль: замените `num = input("Пожалуйста введите цифру")` на `print("Пожалуйста введите цифру")` и удалите первую строку(`num = None`).

Comment: в принципе можно и без цикла обойтись: `if not text.isdigit(): print("введите цифру")`